# How do I show that $\mathbb{E} \max_{i\le N} |X_i| \le CK\sqrt{\log N}$, where $X_i$ are sub-gaussian random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

It's Exercise 2.5.10 in [High Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) by Vershynin.

> **Exercise 2.5.10:**   (Maximum of sub-gaussians). ☕️☕️☕️ Let $X_1, X_2, \dotsc,$ be a sequence of sub-gaussian random variables, which are not necessarily independent.  Show that
> $$ \mathbb{E}\max_{i} \frac{|X_i|}{\sqrt{1+\log i}} \le CK,$$
> where $K = \max_i \|X\|_{\psi_2}$.  Deduce that for every $N\ge 2$ we have
> $$ \mathbb{E}\max_{i\le N} |X_i| \le CK\sqrt{\log N}.$$

I am able to show that $$ \mathbb{E} \max_i \frac{|X_i|}{\sqrt{1+\log i}} \leq CK$$

But when I try to deduce that

$$ \text{For every }N\geq 2, \mathbb{E}\max_{i\leq N} |X_i| \leq CK\sqrt{\log N}$$
I can only show the above inequality for $1\leq i \leq \left \lfloor \frac{N}{e} \right \rfloor $ since $ \sqrt{1+\log i}\leq \sqrt{\log N} \text{ in this range}.$ But for every $N\geq 2$, I cannot find a way to bound it.

Comment: The $C$ does not need to be the same; it just means some positive constant.  So bound $\sqrt{1 + \log i} \leq C' \sqrt{ \log i} \leq \sqrt{\log N}$ for $2 \leq i \leq N$ and some constant $C'$.

Comment: @MarcusM I have tried to solve for $C'$ but it seems that it cannot satisfy $2 \leq i \leq N$

Comment: For $i \geq 2$, $1 \leq 2 \log 2 \leq 2 \log i$ so $\sqrt{1 + \log i} \leq \sqrt{2 \log i + \log i} = \sqrt{3} \sqrt{\log i} \leq \sqrt{3} \sqrt{ \log N}$.